# Convert a URL to a valid win32 filename in Delphi

Tags: delphi, url, filenames, encode

As part of a Delphi application I'm wanting to convert a URL to a filename.  What I'm doing is caching QR-Codes.  The QR-Code represents a URL, and I want to store the QR-Code image with a filename that represents that URL.  For example http://myurl.com/bla might become http___myrul.com_bla.png - here I've just replaced any non alpha-numeric characters with underscores (and added the .png extension).

I was wondering if there was a simple/standard way of doing this (preferably in Delphi) or should I code up the algorithm mentioned above.

Comment: if you are using Delphi XE you could use regular expressions (RegularExpressions unit, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html) although I would not call this approach "simple" :)

Comment: While I have Delphi XE, this project is currently stuck in Delphi 2007

Comment: @yms, @Alister, you can use regular expressions with Delphi 2007 as well, in fact you can use the exact same reg-ex engine. That doesn't mean it's the way to do it. Just because Delphi has regular expressions, they're not automatically the solution to every string processing problem!

Answer (score 7):

try encoding the URL (the returned string will be *always* a valid filename) and then add the extention. also the process is reversable so you can obtain the original url from the filename.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

function URLEncode(const AUrl: string): string;
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for Index := 1 to Length(AUrl) do
  begin
    case AUrl[Index] of
      'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9', '-', '_', '.': Result := Result + AUrl[Index];
      ' '                                        : Result := Result + '%20';
    else
        Result := Result + '%' + IntToHex(Ord(AUrl[Index]), 2);
    end;
  end;
end;

function UrlToFileName(const AUrl,Ext : string) : TFileName;
begin
   Result := Format('%s.%s',[URLEncode(AUrl),Ext]);
end;

begin
  try
    Writeln(UrlToFileName('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784218/convert-a-url-to-a-valid-win32-filename-in-delphi','png'));
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

this will return

```
http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F5784218%2Fconvert-a-url-to-a-valid-
win32-filename-in-delphi.png
```

for additional info read the [`Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions) article.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [PathGetCharType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773608%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function from the Windows API.

```
uses ShLwApi;
...
var s: string;
    i: integer;

begin
  s := 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784218/convert-a-url-to-a-valid-win32-filename-in-delphi';

  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
    if PathGetCharType(s[i]) in [GCT_INVALID, GCT_SEPARATOR] then
      s[i] := '_';

  Writeln(s);
end;
```

> This will return
>   http___stackoverflow.com_questions_5784218_convert-a-url-to-a-valid-win32-filename-in-delphi

Anyway, I was wondering how many functions exists for [path handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Maybe [PathCreateFromUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773581%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) do what you want (except extension addition of course), I haven't tested it yet.